# How to get models in separate file?

Tags: sinatra, datamapper

I saw in someones code that code relayed to model was stored in separate file.
I couldn't get how he requires that file in his app.
There is an example what i mean:

main.rb

```
DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/adserver.db")
class Article
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id,           Serial
    property :title,        String
    has n, :clicks
    def some_method( file )
        ...code
        end
    end
end

class Click
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id,           Serial
    property :user,   String
    belongs_to :Article
end
helpers do
  include Sinatra::Authorization
end

configure :development do
    DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
end
```

How to get this code and other models's related code to separate file, ex: model.rb
and where to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could require the separate file in `main.rb`, e.g.:

```
require File.expand_path('../model.rb', __FILE__)
```

Example assumes file named `model.rb` and placed in the same directory as `main.rb`.

Comment: Thanks! 
One more question can I just 
require 'data_mapper' instead of 
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-timestamps'
etc

Comment: DataMapper is split into modules and it's better to require them explicitly. But you could also use require 'data_mapper' because it [requires](https://github.com/datamapper/data_mapper/blob/master/lib/data_mapper.rb) all modules.